# Prolog Rule for Fact with Structure

Tags: prolog

I have following facts in Prolog. symptom (A,B,C): symptom A in region B can be caused by virus C (abbreviation, full name)

```
symptom(delirium,mind,virus(rbs, rabies)).
symptom(delirium,mind,virus(tbe, tick-borne-encephalitis)).
symptom(discomfort,mind,virus(rbs, rabies)).
...
```

I want to ask what type of viruses can for example cause a specific symptom. For this I want to declare a rule 'causedBy(X,Y)' where in query I could send the symptom and it gives me the list of possible viruses.

The question is how can I just send the symptom and get the list of *only* abbreviations of possible viruses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
causedBy(X,Y) :- symptom(X, _, virus(Y, _)).
```

([demo in SWI Prolog on ideone](http://ideone.com/aq0GJF)).

The process of *unification* is recursive, you can nest names as deeply as you need for unifying with your facts. In this case, `virus(Y, _)` is nested inside `symptom/3` call to "extract" only the first element of the `virus` pair.